# How do I override /libraries/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/lang/some.js?

Tags: 8, javascript, plugins

I'm using [ckwordcount module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckwordcount) which basically adds nice max length and counter features to text Fields, and relies on [WordCount Plugin for CKEditor Editor](https://github.com/w8tcha/CKEditor-WordCount-Plugin).

Most of the translations in the plugin lang directory are incomplete, **resulting in messy *undefined* strings displayed where we'd expect a clear message for end users**...

Just to make sure this was the plugin translation source I edited the original file in `/libraries/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/wordcount/lang/` folder and it works, but for obvious reasons I can't do this way.

So I tried to override that file in many ways, without success.
First in my admin subtheme, I added a js file to declare more CKEditor config variables. The inner part of declaration (`CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang`) is a copy of the original, so I'm sure this is the right syntax :

**admin_subtheme/js/customCkeditorConfig.js**

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.CKEditorConfig = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (typeof CKEDITOR !== "undefined") {
        CKEDITOR.plugins.setLang('wordcount', 'fr', {
          WordCount: 'Mots :',
          WordCountRemaining: 'Mots restants',
          CharCount: 'Caractères :',
          CharCountWithHTML: 'Caractères (incluant HTML) :',
          CharCountWithHTMLRemaining: 'caractère(s) restant(s), incluant les sauts de lignes, espaces ...',
          Paragraphs: 'Paragraphes :',
          ParagraphsRemaining: 'Paragraphes restants',
          pasteWarning: 'Le contenu ne peut pas être collé car il dépasse la limite autorisée',
          Selected: 'Sélectionné :',
          title: 'Statistiques'
        });
      }
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

After clearing caches the file is called but not applied. I guess it might be overridden by the original one that is loaded after ?

I also tried to use the libraries-override syntax in the info.yml file. I could not find any doc that explain how to proceed with external libraries, so I tried whatever I could imagine !

**admin_subtheme.info.yml**

```
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    js:
      /libraries/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/wordcount/lang/fr.js: js/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/fr.js

  libraries/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin:
    js:
      wordcount/lang/fr.js: js/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/fr.js

  core/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin:
    js:
      wordcount/lang/fr.js: js/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/fr.js

  w8tcha/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin:
    js:
      wordcount/lang/fr.js: js/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/fr.js

  global:
    js:
      /libraries/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/wordcount/lang/fr.js: js/ckeditor-wordcount-plugin/fr.js
```

Any idea, please ? Thanks a lot.